# Radio buttons are checked by default, which they shouldn't

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a radio button - if it is selected, it should show the mat-radio-group with Option 1 and Option 2. The mat-radio-group is hidden as intended - however, by default when starting my application, all radio buttons are checked and **I can't uncheck any of them**.

I obviously want them all unchecked when starting, which is/should be default behaviour. What have I done wrong to have them all checked by default?

**Dialog.component.html**

```
<mat-radio-button (click)="toggleDisplay('options')" class="item">See options</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-group *ngIf="doShow('options')" class="item-container">
    <mat-radio-button class="item">Option 1</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button class="item">Option 2</mat-radio-button>
  </mat-radio-group>
</mat-radio-group>
```

**Dialog.component.ts**

```
currentlyShown = '';

toggleDisplay(element: string) {
  this.currentlyShown = element;
}

doShow(element: string): boolean {
  return this.currentlyShown === element;
}
```

Thanks in advance. (**All unneccessary code has been excluded**)

Comment: Please provide Stackblitz

Comment: Radio buttons have **values**. If you don't provide one, they're checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Radio buttons have values. if you don't provide it, they get checked by default.

**[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-96f4hz?file=app/radio-overview-example.html)**

```
<mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option">
  <mat-radio-button value="1">Option 1</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button value="2">Option 2</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button>Option 1</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button>Option 2</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```